# UnixTimestamps always off in ios

Tags: ios, timestamp, nsdate, unix-timestamp

I've tried countless ways of getting the current timestamp and no matter what I do the timestamp is always off. 
What is the proper way to get the right timestamp

```
 NSLog(@"%@",NSTimeIntervalSince1970);
```

Was the closest one however, it's still not right. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSTimeIntervalSince1970 is a #define and gives you the number of seconds between 1970 & 1/1/2001. i.e. it'll always be the same. you want to do something like `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];`